# Integration testing in R

Tags: r

Are there common- or best practices in doing integration tests in R? Or even packages?

I have many modules as scripts in a data pipeline and I was thinking of the following solution:

Collect all inputs as a list object and all outputs as a list object. Then I could replace the input and output objects with input test data and desired output test data and compare.

I was thinking perhaps using the script in a testing mode by passing arguments to docopt or using an environment variable.

Or are integration tests not a thing in R? Should every script rather be some huge function that is properly unit tested?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: It sounds to me like you should be working on a package (internal or otherwise) and include `testthat` unit-testing. With sample-data available to the unit-tests, it can be as unit-level or larger-picture-integrative as you need.

Comment: Thanks! I already use an internal package with unit-tested functions, I was wondering more about writing tests for whole scripts.

Comment: My issue is I may run a script 200 times with different inputs and want to avoid writing tests inside that script, but want to write some quick tests to compare input and output.

Comment: `testthat` supports looping and automating tests on various inputs. If you have a directory of inputs (either each file is a test, or a subdir is a test of files needed for one test), then `list_of_testdata <- lapply(list.files(...), get_test_data)`, then run a test on each element of `list_of_testdata`.

Comment: Otherwise, I don't know how best to answer your question without more context. Sorry, is it possible that this is too detailed (contextual) for a simple SO question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I think I just need to make sure that each section in my script is a function and then in the end I have a main function that calls all the sub functions with the input data. At the very end of the script I can then have some unit tests for the sub functions and some larger tests for the main function that reads some test files. I'll then use some testing flag to make sure the tests are only run when I want them to be run. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Hi @jroman... I'm walking down your path. This is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597073/run-unit-tests-on-git-push-and-integration-tests-on-pull-request. The TL;WR version is that my integration tests take too long, so I want to run them only on Pull-Request, while keeping the normal unit tests running for normal pushes. How did you implement your testing flag?