# Run unit tests on git push and integration tests on pull request

Tags: r, unit-testing, github, integration-testing, travis-ci

When building R packages, we use testthat to write tests. We have 2 files: a test file for the specific package (**specific.R**), and one that we use to make sure all packages continue to work together and the overall result is fine (**overall.R**). Both tests are currently run when we push to github or create a PR through Travis, which implicitly runs this line of code(`R CMD check *tar.gz`). `check` runs all the tests in the test folder, and thus both files are run.

Now, I'm a bit new to testing... but it seems that we have more or less recreated the difference b/w a *unit test* and an *integration test*.

Considering that the tests for `overall.R` do take a lot longer to run, we would like to restrict it so that they only run when we do a pull-request to the package (when we have introduced new functionality on a different dev branch) while the package-specific tests keep running every time we commit/push to the repo.

Is this possible in github or Travis?

Answer (score 1):

You could put your overall.R script into a different directory and then specify this folder as the new tests directory for pull-request hooks, but this will then only run your integration tests and not the unit tests. See R CMD check --help

```
R CMD check --test-dir integration_tests package.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a testthat method that tests only one test. Currently trying to figure out how to get that to fail a Travis run... I'll post a response when I've got it.